# Pandas map equivalent to Numpy

Tags: python

I currently have these two arrays,

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array(["Aaple", "Orange", "Banana"]).reshape(-1,1)

arr2 = np.array([["Strawberry", "Red"], ["Aaple", "Red"], ["Orange", "Orange"], ["Pear", "Yello"], ["Banana", "Yellow"]])

# they print as this
[['Aaple']
 ['Orange']
 ['Banana']]

[['Strawberry' 'Red']
 ['Aaple' 'Red']
 ['Orange' 'Orange']
 ['Pear' 'Yello']
 ['Banana' 'Yellow']]
```

I would like to use a pandas map equivalent where I would get the end result of,

```
 [['Aaple' 'Red']
 ['Orange' 'Orange']
 ['Banana' 'Yellow']]
```

Where I map `arr[:,1]` onto `arr`. How would I do this, I was using `np.where` and I am pretty stuck.

Comment: Are you actually working with `dtype=object` arrays? If so, you should *just use vanilla python data structures*. Like a `dict` and a `list` for all of this.

Comment: Im using strings, I have some more complicated arrays that I want to do this with, just an example of something more simple @juanpa.arrivillaga

Comment: right. Then *you should definitely just use regular python data structures*. It will be more efficient and easier

Comment: I am trying to use something with arrays, is there no easy way to do this with arrays? The other dataset I am trying to use has millions of rows and basic python structures take way too long @juanpa.arrivillaga

Comment: Then convert to a dict, use a dict to create a list, and turn it into an array at the end. There is no quick way to do this with numpy, arrays **are not maps**. If you want a mapping, you *should use a map*, like a `dict`. That will be the most efficient way. So, you can actually just do `colormap = dict(arr2)` then `result = np.array([[x, colormap[x]] for x in arr.ravel()])`

Comment: The other option is to sort your array, then use np.searchsorted, but that will be less efficient and some subtle edge cases